# What are the technical reasons not to use non-reversible transformation when encrypting password in database?

Tags: password-policy

What are the technical reasons not to use non-reversible transformation when encrypting password in database? That way, even when password database is leaked, nobody can read any password. If it is reversible ,it would fail to comply with some standards ,e.g.French National Commission on Informatics and Liberty. Is it due to costs?

Comment: There might be a few technical reasons that passwords are not stored this way (like when supporting Digest authentication) but other then that it is basically asking why not everybody implements best practices. This kind of broad scope leads to primarily opinion based answers and is thus not a good fit for a site.  Maybe you could limit the scope of your question by only asking for technical reasons when passwords can not be stored this way - if this is what you want to know.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich why is supporting digest authentication necessary? Can't they do it in other ways that are more secure?

Comment: This is a different question. And your original question still has the same broad scope. But for example digest authentication is the standard with SIP (voice over IP).

Comment: If you have any links about countries that require this by law, I'd be interested to see

Comment: @paj28 https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/cnil/id/CNILTEXT000035142451/

Comment: @paj28 Look like it is only "recommended"...

Comment: @paj28 but if it is reversible, it does not comply with CNIL .. see this link: https://www.vaadata.com/blog/how-to-securely-store-passwords-in-database/

Comment: CNIL still only "recommends"

Comment: There is no technical reason, except inertia. Some older systems cannot be changed. This really boils down to "why don't people make more secure decisions?" and I'm afraid we can't answer this.